# Dynamic Form Architecture in Angular

Tags: angularjs, forms, web, web-applications, architecture

This question is more theoretical in nature. I'm building a web application using Angular as the front-end and it will have *hundreds of different forms with different number and types of fields*, but generally I think I can generalize them into 4-5 different views. Right now, I create a new view for each and every form because the fields are different and the validations etc are different so in the end I would be left with hundreds of different views for the various forms alone, which is kind of a maintenance nightmare if I need to change the layout or structure. I want **something scalable where I build 4-5 different views and then I can pass on 'parameters' defining the number and types of fields or something like that and have it create all the different forms I need.** Is this possible? If so, where can I read more about it or how do I go about this. I'm new with Angular and want to understand the implications of building in this architecture.

Comment: do you want to use angular1 or angular2 ?

Comment: @WilliPasternak my current front-end theme uses Angular1 but I'm willing to invest time in learning Angular2 if it fixes this problem. I do know, it's revolutionary and mad fast, but this is a huge problem for me and if it fixes this, I'm all up for it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple really nice libraries for easily building different types of forms in angularjs.

[formly](http://angular-formly.com/)

[angular-schema-form](http://schemaform.io/)

They both solve essentially the same problem, but each has their own flavour.  It depends how you'd like to use it.

I personally love angular-schema-form's approach of using standardized json-schema definitions.  I haven't used Formly, but it does seem to be pretty popular.